# Elastic Beanstalk host specific application configuration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a java web application I'm trying to re-factor to work with the elastic beanstalk way of doing things.  The application will be load balanced and have (for the moment) 2 hosts without taking any advantage of auto-scaling.  The issue is that there are slight configuration differences between the nodes,  in particular authenticating to certain web-services is done with different credentials to effectively double throughput as there are per account throttling restrictions.

Currently my application treats configuration separately from the archive so its relatively simple on fixed hosts where the configuration remains in a relatively static file path and deployment of the war files is all that is required.

Going down the elastic beanstalk path I think I'll have to include all the configuration options inside the deployable artifact and some how get the application to load up the relevant host specific configuration.  The problem I have is deciding which configuration to load inside the application.  I could use a physical aspect about the host, i.e. an IP address or Instance ID that would effectively load the relevant config;

```
/config-<InstanceID-1>.properties 
/config-<InstanceID-2>.properties
```

This approach is totally flawed given that if I create an entirely new environment in beanstalk, it would require me to update all the configuration files in the project to reflect the new Instance-id's created.

Has anyone come up with a good way of doing this in beanstalk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to have two different types of nodes, then you should consider SOA architecture for your application.

Create two environments, `environment-a` and `environment-b`. Either set all properties for the environments through AWS web console, or can reuse your existing configuration files and just set the specific configuration file name for each environment.

```
#environment-a
PARAM1 = config-environment-a.properties

#environment-b
PARAM1 = config-environment-b.properties
```

You share the same code base and push to either environment with `-e` modifier.

```
#push to environment-a
$ git aws.push -e environment-a

#push to environment-b
$ git aws.push -e environment-b
```

You can also create git alias to push to both environments at the same time :-)

Now, the major benefit of SOA approach is that you can scale and manage those environments separately. It is simple and elegant.

If you want more complex and less elegant, use simple token distribution service. On every environment initialization, send two messages to Amazon SQS. Each message should contain configuration name. Then pull those messages from SQS, each instance will get exactly one from the queue. Whichever configuration name the message contains, configure your node with that configuration. :-)

Hope it helps.

**Update after** @vcetinick **comment:**

> All still seems rather complex for what should be pretty simple.

That's why I suggested separate environments. You can make your own registration service, when the node comes up, it registers with the service and in return gets configuration params. You keep *available* configurations in persistent DB. If the node dies and the service gets another registration request, the registration service can quickly check registered all nodes (because they all left their info during the registration), and if any of the nodes is not responding, its configuration data is reassigned to the new node. And now you have [single point of failure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure) on your hands :-)

Again, there might be other ways to approach that problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply, only problem in my case is it seems a little unjustified to split into 2 environments for what is just really 2 usernames and passwords difference in config.  And when node 3 and 4 come along adding environments again... I like the SQS idea but yeah would have to load up the SQS service prior to application config so the application is initialized with the correct config, but if an instance was powered off suddenly, would need to somehow push config element back into queue.  All still seems rather complex for what should be pretty simple.

Comment: @vcetinick: updated the answer - it was too long for the comment :-)